# how to replace space between strings in an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

i have an array as follows

```
 [ 'category','book id','author book','book 
    title','price','publication','publication date' ]
```

i want to replace space between the string elements with underscore.
My expected output is

```
  [ 'category','book_id','author_book',
    'book_title','price','publication','publication_date' ]
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 1):

Use `array#map` with `string#replace`

```js
var data = [ 'category','book id','author book','book title','price','publication','publication date' ],
    result = data.map(word => word.replace(' ', '_'));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: This worked .. thank you :-)if  it is a json array then how can i  modify the code?

Comment: The code will work for an array.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let input = [ 'category','book id','author book','book title','price','publication','publication date' ]

let output = input.map( word => word.replace(" ","_") )

// Or for ALL spaces in string : .replace(/ /g, "_")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
newArray = oldArray.map(elem => elem.replace(" ", "_"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr =  [ 'category','book_id','author_book',
    'book_title','price','publication','publication_date' ];
    
    arr = arr.map(function(data){
       if(data.split(" ").length>1){
          data.join("_")
       }
     return data;
       
    
    })

   console.log(arr)
```